# Can you please tell me what's wrong with this string input code block,it keeps giving segmentation fault

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    char *str;
    int len;
    printf("Enter the expression: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", &str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    len = strlen(str);
    printf("%d\n", len);
}
```

I am trying input a string into a string pointer but it keeps giving me a segmentation error, however when i initialize it as char array it works fine.

Comment: Hint: where is `str` pointing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `char *str;`, exactly what do you think this means? What is your understanding of what a pointer is? **Where** do you think this pointer is pointing, and why? What do you expect to happen, if data is written to that location?

Comment: I think the declaration of `main` would be the first thing a normal C compiler would complain about. Sam: What is the name of the compiler you use?

Comment: `str` is of type `char *`, so `&str` is of type `char **`, but the `%[` conversion specifier needs a `char *`, and you are giving it a `char **`

Comment: sam tenison, Save time and enable all warnings.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank You so much, I just grasped that it was all because it was a double pointer.I am a student and what you pointed out about %[ was new to me, so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to get `scanf` to allocate the necessary memory for the string. That option is only available as an extension in some implementations, but here's how that would work:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {                        // note the proper declaration
    char *str = NULL;
    int len;
    printf("Enter the expression: \n");
    if(scanf("%m[^\n]", &str) == 1) {   // add `m` to malloc memory for the string
        printf("%s\n", str);
        len = strlen(str);
        printf("%d\n", len);
        free(str);                      // and `free` it after use
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using the `scanf` function to write to an uninitialized pointer `str`. The `&` is also uneeded for passing a pointer for `scanf`. A better way to handle the input would be to use `fgets()` or `getline()` and allocating memory dynamically using `malloc()` to store the input string.